# Ordering a dataframe with a key function and multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, 'D', 'C'],
    'col2': [2, -1, 9, -8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
    'col4': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F'],
    'col5': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col6': [1.00005,1.00001,-2.12132, -2.12137,1.00003,-2.12135]
})

print(df)

print(df.sort_values(by=['col5']))

print(df.sort_values(by=['col2']))

print(df.sort_values(by='col2', key=lambda col: col.abs() ))
```

So far so good.

However I would like to order the dataframe by two columns:
First col6 and then col5

However, with the following conditions:

- col6 only has to consider 4 decimals (meaning that `1.00005` and `1.00001` should be consider equal
- col6 should be considered as absolute (meaning `1.00005` is less than `-2.12132`)

So the desired output would be

```
  col1  col2  col3 col4  col5     col6
1    A    -1     1    B     1  1.00001
0    A     2     0    a     2  1.00005
4    D     7     2    e     7  1.00003
5    C     4     3    F     4 -2.12135
3  NaN    -8     4    D     8 -2.12137
2    B     9     9    c     9 -2.12132
```

How can I combine the usage of keys with multiple columns?

Comment: In your example you use twice col6, which one is col5? ;)

Comment: @mozway I am sorry where?

Comment: I think I understood, you want to sort first by col6 absolute value truncated to the 4 first decimal, then by col5. The way it was phrased was confusing to me but I got it now ;) Check the first part of my answer for a generic way to consider different functions for sorting, and the last part for your specific case

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use arbitrary conditions on different columns, the easiest (ans most efficient) is to use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
import numpy as np

out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([df['col5'].abs(), df['col6'].round(4)])]
```

*NB. unlike `sort_values`, the keys with higher priority are in the end with `lexsort`.*

If you really want to use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), you can use a custom function that choses the operation to apply depending on the Series name:

```
def sorter(s):
    funcs = {
        'col5': lambda s: s.abs(),
        'col6': lambda s: s.round(4)
    }
    return funcs[s.name](s) if s.name in funcs else s
    
out = df.sort_values(by=['col6', 'col5'], key=sorter)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3 col4  col5     col6
5    C     4     3    F     4 -2.12135
3  NaN    -8     4    D     8 -2.12137
2    B     9     9    c     9 -2.12132
1    A    -1     1    B     1  1.00001
4    D     7     2    e     7  1.00003
0    A     2     0    a     2  1.00005
```

##### provided example

reading again the question and the provided example, I think you might want:

```
df.iloc[np.lexsort([df['col5'], np.trunc(df['col6'].abs()*10**4)/10**4])]
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3 col4  col5     col6
1    A    -1     1    B     1  1.00001
0    A     2     0    a     2  1.00005
4    D     7     2    e     7  1.00003
5    C     4     3    F     4 -2.12135
3  NaN    -8     4    D     8 -2.12137
2    B     9     9    c     9 -2.12132
```

Comment: abs and round are both for col6

Comment: @KansaiRobot yes, I got if after answering check the last part for what you want. I still left the first part as a general discussion that might be interesting to others ;)

Comment: This answer is too good to be true and the sorter is the crown jewel. Just one question I have, in `np.lexsort` is it correct that secondary key will only affect the output arrays in case there are duplicated values in primary key?

Comment: @Anoushiravan Yes. Note that the primary key is the **last** one (vs **first** one in `sort_values`)

Answer (score 1):

`round()` should not be used to truncate because `round(1.00005, 4) = 1.0001`.

**Proposed code :**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, 'D', 'C'],
    'col2': [2, -1, 9, -8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
    'col4': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F'],
    'col5': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col6': [1.00005,1.00001,-2.12132, -2.12137,1.00003,-2.12135]
})

r = df.sort_values(by=['col6', 'col5'], key=lambda c: c.apply(lambda x: abs(float(str(x)[:-1]))) if c.name=='col6' else c)

print(r)
```

**Result :**

```
  col1  col2  col3 col4  col5     col6
1    A    -1     1    B     1  1.00001
0    A     2     0    a     2  1.00005
4    D     7     2    e     7  1.00003
5    C     4     3    F     4 -2.12135
3  NaN    -8     4    D     8 -2.12137
2    B     9     9    c     9 -2.12132
```

**Other coding style inspired from Mozway**

I have read the inspiring @Mozway way.

Very interesting but like s is a serie you should use the following script :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, 'D', 'C'],
    'col2': [2, -1, 9, -8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
    'col4': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F'],
    'col5': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col6': [1.00005,1.00001,-2.12132, -2.12137,1.00003,-2.12135]
})

def truncate(x):
    s = str(x).split('.')
    s[1] = s[1][:4]
    return '.'.join(s)

def sorter(s):
    funcs = {
        'col5': lambda s: s,
        'col6': lambda s: s.apply(lambda x: abs(float(truncate(x))))
    }
    return funcs[s.name](s) if s.name in funcs else s
    
out = df.sort_values(by=['col6', 'col5'], key=sorter)

print(out)
```